# Aggregate function and order by clause in sql

Tags: sql-server

```
Insert into dbo.Cache(StringSearched, ColName, RowId, PercentMatch) select ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber, Max(Percentage) from #Temp2 Group by ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber order By Percentage desc
```

Above SQL statement gives error as follows :

```
Column "#Temp2.Percentage" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I have used `MAX` function with Percentage i.e `MAX(Percentage)`  and yet I am getting above mentioned error.How do I fix this  ?

Comment: why do you insert ordered? insert as is and do the order you want when querying dbo.Cache

Comment: Yes, i was stupid in doing that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the column an alias, then you can use it in the order by.

```
Insert into dbo.Cache(
    StringSearched, 
    ColName, 
    RowId, 
    PercentMatch) 
select 
    ValFromUser, 
    ColumnName, 
    RowNumber, 
    Max(Percentage) as MaxPerc 
from 
    #Temp2 
Group by 
    ValFromUser, 
    ColumnName, 
    RowNumber 
order By 
    MaxPerc desc
```

Also, unless your table has an identity field or something like that, using order by with insert is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining order in tables in this fashion is more or less pointless though as you're not guaranteed to get rows back in any specific order unless you include an order by when retrieving.

That said, you can either reuse the function in the order by:

```
Insert into dbo.Cache (StringSearched, ColName, RowId, PercentMatch) 
select ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber, Max(Percentage) 
from #Temp2 
Group by ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber 
Order By max(Percentage) desc
```

Or give the ccolumn an alias and use that:

```
Insert into dbo.Cache (StringSearched, ColName, RowId, PercentMatch) 
select ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber, Max(Percentage) Perc
from #Temp2 
Group by ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber 
Order By Perc Desc
```